# Background image for header doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, css

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
        ....
        </div>
        <div class="main"></div>
....
</form>
</body>
```

And the css file:

```
body   
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
}

.page
{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;
    border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;border: 2px solid white;padding: 1px 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 3px 5px #ccc;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: white; 
    background-image: url(~/img/056.JPG);// I want it displays as a image logo
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;

}
```

I've tried many way to set image (logo) for header even I put the line:
 `background-image: url(~/img/056.JPG);` but `056.JPG` image doesn't appear in header (just only background color).

Then I do this way:

```
<div class="header">
            <img style="border:0px" src="img/056.JPG" height="200px" width="100%" alt=""/>
</div>
```

The image appeared, but that is not the way I want. Because, when I set the image logo for header as the way above then I put some  new tag `<div>` inside the `<div header>` --> that  `new <div>` will be displayed below the header (I want it displays inside the header).

help, is there any mistake in my header div, why the background image doesn't show???

UPDATE:

as recommended, I've just edited the url, I use `Banner2009_new.jpg` instead of `056.JPG`:

```
background-image: url("/website/pic/Banner2009_new.jpg");
```

Then, I double click on the path image to check: 
[image]

It still has file: `Banner2009_new.jpg` in `pic` folder webpage, but when I check, it seems there no Banner2009_new.jpg

This is my website folder:[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A url for `background-image` that is relative to the root of your website looks like this

```
url("/img/056.JPG")
```

(No tilda `~`)

Edit: According to your comments, for your local development hosting environment, your web-root folder is the parent folder of "website". You would need to give the url

```
url("/website/img/056.JPG")
```

If you want the root of the site to be the parent folder "website", you can either move all of website folder contents up to the parent folder, or configure a virtual host on your web server to point to the "website" folder given a domain name you specify (probably in the hosts file) (but that's another topic). [This may](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53856/using-apaches-rewrite-module-to-set-up-local-host-names-for-development) help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm.. Did you try flushing browser cache?

Comment: Tell me the path to the file that has the html, e.g. `<div class="header"` from the root of your site.

Comment: So for this particular environment, the "root" of your website is **not** the "website" folder, it is its parent folder. So you need to give the path `"/website/img/056.JPG"`

Comment: I put all the aspx page, master page and img folder in a website folder. As you recommended, I add: "/website/img/056.JPG" --> error: Path D:\C#Projects\website\website not found

Comment: What?? Why is it "\website\website"?

Comment: I've just update my question, I use the same picture with different name in pic folder. Please take a look at my update

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, except maybe make sure your css file is being loaded and that the styles are being overridden somewhere. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the image as a background, you need to set it as `background-image` in your CSS. Adding it as an `<img>` within your header div is just gonna add it as an inline image.

You had it right the first time, you just need to remove the tilde (`~`) from the URL:

```
background-image: url(/img/056.JPG);
```

Comment: Double check the path to the image, otherwise try setting `width` to the actual width of the image in px.

Comment: I've just updated my question, please take a look at my update above